# Plotting hundreds of hours of data with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, time-series

I am trying to plot data from a simulation that tracks simulation time in (hours):(minutes):(seconds) format, but does not turn (hours) into days - so (hours) can be in the hundreds. When gnuplot plots data by time, however ("set xdata time"), it only plots up to 99 hours in one continuous plot; after that, it loops back around and starts overplotting hour 100+ near the beginning (and even then, does weird stuff). Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to get around it?

I also looked into reading the components of the time column (which is the 3rd field of data on each line, but not necessarily a fixed number of characters into the line) in as 3 simple numbers (integers), then converting to a real number, which happens to be a decimal version of the time (e.g., 107:45:00 -> 107.75), which would be fine for the plot, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get gnuplot to do that, either.

Any other ideas are welcome.  (I would rather not alter the original file, due to the additional complexity of multiple versions of each file, having to teach others how to convert the file and how to figure out the plot didn't work because they didn't convert the file, etc.)

Comment: Could you post an example of your data file? This would make it a lot easier to reproduce your problem and suggest a possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 of [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) (GPL plotting library) have time ticks which can be set as you want (using standard strftime() format). However it is in beta version now -- stable version should appear at October 2011.